# Magento Admin: Limit Characters in Grid via Add Column

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

We're using Magento CE 1.9.1.

I can't seem to find an answer to this.

I've added a column for a module admin grid.  I want to limit the length of the string when the data populates the cell.

Is there an option for `$this->addColumn` which allows this?  The only suggestion I have found is `string_limit`, but that did not work.

**Edit**

Here's what I'm seeing.

[image]

I want to limit the visible characters in this field so I don't display the entire string.

The code that generates this column in `protected function _prepareColumns()`:

```
$this->addColumn('testimonial', array(
    'header'       => Mage::helper('testimonial')->__('Testimonial'),
    'align'        => 'left',
    'index'        => 'testimonial',
));
```

The only suggestion I found to accomplish what I want was adding `'string_limit' => '{some number}'` to the `addColumn` option array.  Didn't work.

Comment: can you show me how you are displaying ? and template location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the file in local folder or just copy app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Testimonial\Grid.php to app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Testimonial\Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('testimonial')->__('Testimonial'),
    'index'     => 'testimonial'
));
```

replace it by

```
$this->addColumn('namewithprifx', array(
   'header'    => Mage::helper('testimonial')->__('Testimonial'),
    'index'     => 'testimonial',
    'type'  => 'text',      
    'width' => '250px',
    'sortable'  =>false,
    'filter' => false,                                         
    'renderer' => 'NameSpace_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Namewithprifx',          
    ));
```

Create file in NameSpace\Customergrid\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Namewithprifx.php

```
    <?php
 class NameSpace_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Namewithprifx extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
 {
   public function render(Varien_Object $row)
   {

    //$getData = $row->getData();               
    $str=$row->getData('prefix'). " ". $row->getData('testimonial');
    return $str; //you can use substr or any php function here
  }
}
```

clear cache and try

Comment: Thanks.  I had a feeling I was going to have to go down this route, I was just sure there was a way to do with with a custom renderer.